# Get width of reCaptcha and use it to set text field width?

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

On my website I have a google reCaptcha and well it just makes my login form look really ugly.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

So I was looking around and found a website with a login form like this

[image]

Which looks really good, it's fully responsive and all. I was curious on a way to do this? Haven't really been able to find any examples of how to do this with a google reCaptcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using table and setting `text-box` width to `100%`

Example Code :

```
<table>
            <tr><td>
                <input type="text" style="width:100%;"><br>
            </tr></td>
            <tr><td>
                <input  class="scaleR" type="text" style="width:100%;"><br></tr></td>
            <tr><td>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE_KEY" data-callback="checked"></div>
            </tr></td>
        </table>
```

Result :

[image]